# What am I supposed to look at Android ANRs?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I have an React Native app and sometimes it crashes giving me the option to send the feedback. When I access ANRs & crashes from Google Play Console I got a bunch of logs, but I'm not sure what that means.

In resume, the topics are

```
"main" tid=1 Native
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=2 Native
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting
"FinalizerDaemon" tid=5 Waiting
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=6 Waiting
"Binder:24455_1" tid=8 Native
"Binder:24455_2" tid=9 Native
"Profile Saver" tid=10 Native
"queued-work-looper" tid=11 Native
"Queue" tid=13 Waiting
"Queue" tid=14 Waiting
"Queue" tid=15 Waiting
"Queue" tid=16 Waiting
"Queue" tid=17 Waiting
"Queue" tid=18 Waiting
"Queue" tid=19 Waiting
"Queue" tid=20 Waiting
"Queue" tid=21 Waiting
"Crashlytics Exception Handler1" tid=22 Waiting
"Answers Events Handler1" tid=23 Waiting
"OkHttp ConnectionPool" tid=26 TimedWaiting
"RenderThread" tid=28 Native
"HybridData DestructorThread" tid=29 Waiting
"Binder:24455_3" tid=30 Native
"mqt_js" tid=31 Native
"mqt_native_modules" tid=32 Native
"OSH_WritePrefs" tid=33 Native
"Signal Catcher" tid=3 Runnable
"HeapTaskDaemon" tid=7 Blocked
```

I won't give all the logs, because it's too much. But the first `"main" tid=1 Native` has:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73e2a870 self=0x796e8c0a00
| sysTid=24455 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x797309b9b0
| state=S schedstat=( 62495905795 17738489601 195362 ) utm=5213 stm=1036 core=4 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fcb7ee000-0x7fcb7f0000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000001dd6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 0000000000065d44  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+96)
#02  pc 0000000001da88dc  /data/app/com.android.chrome-YPgu5fbzu8Na_XBkB4z-ag==/base.apk (???)
at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.nativeOnVSync (Native method)
at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.a (PG:220)
at cKD.a (PG:16)
at cKm.doFrame (PG:24)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:964)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:778)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:710)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:952)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6595)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

So, does this or any other topic above have any valuable information?

Comment: Are you using AdMob ads? We have this in our app, and I think the slow rendering is caused by the ads being shown. These are shown in a WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "topics" are a list of threads and stack traces on those threads. So the first list shows you have threads:

- a main thread (for rendering UI)
- some queues
- some finalizers for garbage collecting objects

etc.

The second part you quote is a stack trace. This shows you what the thread is doing, in this case the main thread. An ANR (Application Not Responding) is normally caused by something slow running on the main thread, so this is useful.

You can see from this that the code is in `org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.nativeOnVSync (Native method)`. So this suggests something you are creating in react is rendering really slowly in the WebView.